# sklearn PCA - Calculate % of variance retained for choosing k

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

I am using scikit learn PCA and trying to choose the minimum number of components that satisfies 1-(sum i 1 to k Sii)/(sum j 1 to n Sjj) <= 0.01 where S is the svd diagonal matrix, in order to have 99% of the variance retained.

1. Does scikit learn has a function that returns minimum components for a given variance retained % threshold?
2. Is there a more efficient way to come up with n_component?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply set `n_components` to be `float`, and it will be used as a lower bound of explained variance.

From [scikit-learn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html)

> **n_components** : int, None or string
>
> Number of components to keep. if n_components is not set all components are kept:
>   n_components == min(n_samples, n_features)
>   if n_components == ‘mle’, Minka’s MLE is used to guess the dimension **if 0 < n_components < 1, select the number of components such that the amount of variance that needs to be explained is greater than the percentage specified by n_components**

Comment: Where in the code do we specify that we need x% of variance retained?

Comment: It is literally stated in the answer. Pass n_components as a float to the PCA constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your question #1 - to get the lowest number of components for a given variance retained % threshold:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA as sklearnPCA
sklearn_pca = sklearnPCA(n_components = 0.99, svd_solver ='full')
```

Regarding your question #2 - following arguments - Minka's maximum-likelihood estimation - will guess the number of principal components:

```
...
sklearn_pca = sklearnPCA(n_components = "mle", svd_solver ="full")
```